# SwiftUI set corner radius depending on its own height

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, radius, clipped

When I set corner radius with constant value, depending on the size of the image, the results don't come out the way I want.

```swift
Image(“myImage”)
    .cornerRadius(25)
```

What I want in app.
[image]
More clipped in Widget
[image]
So I want to set radius value like  `image.size.height / 5`, depending on its own size.

When I think about overlay, code will be like below,

```swift
Image("myImage")
.overlay(
    GeometryReader { geo in
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: geo.size.height / 5)
    }
)
```

but when it comes to clipShape to apply corner radius, I don't know how to do.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-clip-a-view-so-only-part-is-visible

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please add more code that you use and write what effect you are trying to achieve. For now I can only guess that `.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)` will solve issue of different previews.

Answer (score 0):

Try using clip shape with Circle as shape -
Using it with an aspect ratio will give you a perfectly square image and content mode will make sure the image fits perfectly.

Use something like this -

```
Image(“myImage”)
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .clipShape(Circle())
```